# How do I get looping result?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, codeigniter

How do I get looping result? See the comment can't get result in code.

```
public function get_data_by_7_days()
    {   

    $arr = array();
        for ($i=7;$i>=0;$i--)
        {
            $run=0;
            $run=$run-$i;

            $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
            $arr     = $this->M_vodor->get_data_by_7_days($username,$run);

        }
        echo json_encode($arr); //cant get result 
}
```

This is my model **M_vodor.php**

```
public function get_data_by_7_days($username,$run)
{

    return $this->db->query("
    SELECT
    DAYNAME(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL $run DAY) ,'%Y-%m-%d')) AS date_checker,
    DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL $run DAY) ,'%d-%m-%Y') AS show_date")->result();}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with MySQL?

Comment: Ok. Edit your question accordingly

Comment: First of all, inside your for loop change $arr=... to $arr[]=... You have to add records to array.

Comment: @1stlife you don't have anything to do with mysql.You can do all thing in controller itself.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to your question with some performence improvments.

```
public function get_data_by_7_days() {   
    $arr = array();
    $username = $this->session->userdata('username'); //if you put this inside the loop, it will read sessions 7 times which affects perfomance
     for ($i=7;$i>=0;$i--){
         $run=0;
            $run=$run-$i;
            $arr[] = $this->M_vodor->get_data_by_7_days($username,$run); //you should use $arr[]
       }
       echo json_encode($arr);
}
```